# Using SAS Token with Azure ServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, .net-standard-2.0, sas-token

I am using new Azure ServiceBus SDK which is .NET Standard 2.0 and I am finding it difficult to use SAS Token. Previously, it used to be MessagingFactory but in new SDK it's not there. ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder has SAS Token but it also expects a connectionString.

Basically, I want to Send and Receive using SAS Policy (Send rule for Sending and Receive rule for Receiving) and SAS token created from connection string of these policies.

I am able to generate SAS Token but cannot find a way to create QueueClient using this token.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you would still need to create a connection string from the SAS policy.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, connection strings can be used but then I won't be able to use SAS Token. I have created SAS Token using connection string.

Comment: That's the whole idea. You create a SAS Policy and the use either its primary or secondary key to create a connection string in the following format: `Endpoint=sb://<namespacename>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<sas-policy-name>;SharedAccessKey=<sas-key>`.

Comment: It still uses SAS Key associated with policy which do not have an expiry. Where is the use of SAS token ? I want to use an expiring SAS token generated from .NET Program. Format of which is like this `SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI> `

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I misunderstood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208038/discussion-between-as1-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: I think I found an answer to your problem. Let me post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using following override of [`ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringbuilder.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_) that uses a SharedAccess Signature:

```
public ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder (string endpoint, string entityPath, string sharedAccessSignature);
```

Based on this, here's the code I wrote. This first generates a SAS token using `RootManagedAccessKey` that is valid for an hour and then uses that token to send a message to a queue.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Primitives;

namespace SO60273377
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpoint = "sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/";
            var queueName = "test";
            var keyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
            var keyValue = "<key>";
            var validityDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

            TokenScope tokenScope = TokenScope.Entity;
            
            var provider = (SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider) TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(keyName, keyValue, validityDuration, tokenScope);
            
            var token = provider.GetTokenAsync(endpoint+queueName, validityDuration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var sasToken = token.TokenValue;
            Console.WriteLine("SAS Token: " + sasToken);
            var serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(endpoint, queueName, sasToken);
            QueueClient client = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            client.SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test"))).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works.On further debugging I also found  `ServiceBusConnectionStringuilder` also has `TokenProvider` property. I was looking for `MessagingFactory` alternative to create `QueueClient`, didn't realize `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuiilder` is the one.

Comment: Not able to create token using new package "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus". any idea how?